# Memory Warning using google maps version 1.3.1 in ios 6.1?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, google-maps, ios6

In iOS 6.1, integrated google maps version 1.3.1. when navigate place, there is error was occur. "Received Memory Warning".Its working in simulator but not in device.

**my code :**

```
             GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[show_lat         doubleValue] longitude:[show_long doubleValue] zoom:15];

            [mapView_ animateToCameraPosition:camera];


            mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.mapview.bounds camera:camera];
            mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
            mapView_.settings.compassButton = YES;
            mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
            [self.mapview addSubview:mapView_];


            // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
            GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
            marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([show_lat doubleValue],[show_long doubleValue]);
            marker.title = selected_branchName;
            marker.snippet = selected_city;
            marker.map = mapView_;
```

Can anyone know please help me...

Answer (score 0):

no, sorry

thats a known issue and *the* top issue reported on the gms-api-ios issue tracker

only google can fix it because it is IN the maps component